# Matplotlib plot only updates when windows is closed?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, graph, graphics

I wrote the following script to display a simple sine curve to update ad infinitum:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from math import sin
n = 0
As =[]
Ns = []
def animate(i):
    As.append(sin(n))
    Ns.append(n)
    ax1.plot(np.array(Ns),np.array(As))

while True:
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, interval=1)
    n = n + 0.05
    plt.show()
```

However the line only updates (as in changes shape at all) when i try to close the window, I can't find anything to fix this - how would it be done? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `n` inside `animate` to add different point - now you add always the same point so you don't see difference. Try `print(Ns)` inside `animate` in your code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from math import sin

n = 0
As = []
Ns = []

# -----

def animate(i):
    global n

    Ns.append(n)
    As.append(sin(n))
    ax1.plot(Ns, As)

    n += 0.05

# -----

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, interval=1)
plt.show()
```

BTW: you can use `i`

```
def animate(i):

    n = 0.05 * i

    Ns.append(n)
    As.append(sin(n))
    ax1.plot(Ns, As)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works really well - what does the line `spherical n` do?

Comment: after the line `def animate(i)` in your amended code?